# Does it take 21 days to form a habit?

Tags: psychology

The Meme:

> - [It takes at least 21 days to form a habit.](http://habitforge.com/)
> - [Personal Development It Takes 21 Days To Form A Habit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf-CKB6f3V8)
> - [Research shows that it takes 21 days to develop a habit.](http://www.stevenaitchison.co.uk/blog/a-new-habit/)
> - [Get Things Done - It Takes 21 Days to Form a Habit](http://www.getorganizednow.com/art-21.html)
> - [It Takes 21 Days To Form A Habit.](http://mydietingsite.com/?p=1080)
> - [Why 21 days? Well, there are a few reasons: First, it takes 21 days to form a habit](http://www.theminimalists.com/21days/)

A counter view:

> - [21 Days To Form a Habit, (Absolute Lie)](http://ihatedoingthisalot.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/21-days-to-form-habit-absolute-lie.html)

This idea seems largely meaningless to me. I don't know if Pavlovian conditioning to a stimulus counts as a habit, but if so, it can be done in minutes.

My question is where is this meme from? Is there, at its base, any research (as at least one of them claimed)?

Comment: I can get in a habit in a few days

Comment: @ratchet You can't call it a habit, if you've had it less than 21 (or n > a few) days :)

Comment: I call a habit something I do regularly and am uncomfortable not doing (for no real reason), I can get into that very easily (hell my habit of opening SE on a new window came in less than a week and remains until now for over 8 months now

Comment: some drugs can be addictive with one or a very few doses (think heroin). I'd call BS without a very strict definition of "habit".

Comment: The definition seems key. Do you think this would be a better question if I asked: Is there any reasonable definition of habit for which this statement has been demonstrated to be (non-tautologically) true?

Comment: Quick ironic disproof: psychology-related data is always statistical and has big dispersion, and it's extremely unlikely to have it ~5%. So anyone who claims "21 days" (not "about 20 days" or "3 weeks") and doesn't provide dispersion has probably done his research in a wrong way.

Comment: Anecdotal : While I'm sure the 21 days is not accurate, the theory probably is. I do remember watching a tv show where a guest made a similar claim. Anyways, I used to have a really, really, really bad habit of not knowing where I left my keys. So I decided to try follow the advice, which was to develop a habit that you want, you need to make sure you do it every single time for 21 days. If you mess up once, you have to start over. I tried the experiment and for the last 20 years or so, I never lose my keys. They go in a specific location without my ever having to think about it, every day.

Comment: This technique works for me in many ways. I am your classical absent-minded professor type. Without a system I am lost. If something goes out of place, it can take weeks before that thing is righted again. So while the exactly 21 days claim, is not valid as the length of time could vary between people and habit trying to be developed, I am certain that The technique to develop a habit works very well for me and I'm sure many others.

Comment: @Dunk: It's a lovely idea, but the question isn't "Did Dunk develop a good habit?" but "Is it true?" The answer I give shows that this isn't true.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Your study showed that 21 days is not true for everybody. If 21-days was the sole goal then you did prove it with your study but you also didn't need a study because it is obvious that not everybody would take the exact same amount of time. The part of the study you did leave out in your quotes was where the researchers believe the habit forming method does work "With repetition of a behaviour in a consistent context, automaticity increases following an asymptotic curve which can be modelled at the individual level." Thus, 21 days not true; able to develop the habit = true.

Comment: "it is obvious that not everybody would take the exact same amount of time" - that is directly in conflict with the links listed in the original question; hence the question. The idea that repeated behaviour helps develop a habit, on the other hand, is something that *I* find blindingly obvious, so that part of the conclusion wasn't exciting to me. Maybe I would be a better skeptic if I *hadn't* assumed that.

Answer (score 5):

**No, the 21-day habit rule is pseudo-scientific.**

First, it can take much longer:

- Phillippa Lally, Cornelia H. M. van Jaarsveld, Henry W. W. Potts, Jane Wardle. [How are habits formed: Modelling habit formation in the real world](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ejsp.674/abstract), European Journal of Social Psychology, Volume 40, Issue 6, pages 998–1009, October 2010, DOI: 10.1002/ejsp.674

These researchers asked 96 volunteers to form a daily habit, over a 12 week period, and record their progress.

> The majority (82) of participants provided sufficient data for analysis, and increases in automaticity (calculated with a sub-set of SRHI items) were examined over the study period. Nonlinear regressions fitted an asymptotic curve to each individual's automaticity scores over the 84 days. The model fitted for 62 individuals, of whom 39 showed a good fit. Performing the behaviour more consistently was associated with better model fit. **The time it took participants to reach 95% of their asymptote of automaticity ranged from 18 to 254 days; indicating considerable variation in how long it takes people to reach their limit of automaticity and highlighting that it can take a very long time.** Missing one opportunity to perform the behaviour did not materially affect the habit formation process.

The source of the myth has been traced by Guardian columnist Oliver Burkeman who [writes](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2009/oct/10/change-your-life-habit-28-day-rule):

> We probably owe this particular example of pop-psychology wisdom to Maxwell Maltz, the plastic surgeon who wrote the 60s bestseller Psycho-Cybernetics. He claimed to have observed that amputees took an average of only 21 days to adjust to the loss of a limb. Therefore, he reasoned – deploying the copper-bottomed logic we've come to expect from self-help – the same must be true of all big changes. And therefore it must take 21 days to change a habit, maybe, perhaps!

Comment: Interestingly enough though, reading through the journal article it looks like there might be a grain of truth to the 21-day habit claim. Based upon the charts it looks like habits tend to be formed after 20 to 40 days and it looks like if you don't have the habit by the end of that period you are unlikely to acquire it. I'd be curious to see what the median time is for 50% of the population to acquire a habit is. Also, what do you mean by "pseudo-scientific" in this case?

Comment: @Rob Z: So there is a grain of truth in the idea that if you repeat something for long enough, it is likely to gain "automaticity", i.e. becomes a habit? Sure. I think Maltz's claim is pseudoscientific, in that it is dressed as a scientific claim (the original quoted texts said 'research shows' - the appearance of scientific support helped the meme spread) but there was almost zero actual scientific evidence backing it.

Comment: No, I mean the grain of truth is that 21 days might be a reasonable minimum estimate for how long it takes for something to become a habit. Granted the way it is written is extremely poor but as a potential grain a truth behind the myth...